# CSS Triangle For Testimonial Box

Tags: css

I have a testimonials box that I would like to add a triangle to.

```
.arrow {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid #eee;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

The problem is the triangle ends up being solid, as opposed to white with a gray border. Below is a screenshot of how the CSS currently displays. Thanks in advance for the time and help.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can have a triangle with border with CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two triangles, one that overlaps the other, to create this bordered effect. You can do this with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements so that you don't even have any superfluous HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/7K2c4/

```
.mybox {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.mybox:before, 
.mybox:after { position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: -19px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0 25px 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #fff;
    content: ' ';
}
.mybox:before { left: 19px;
    bottom: -21px;
    border-left-color: #ccc; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place another triangle over it, smaller with the same color of the box background. You don't even need to create another HTML element, just use a pseudo-element selector.